# Rocker RStudio restore project when running docker compose?

Tags: docker, rstudio

I am trying to restore an existing project when I run `docker compose up`, the base image is  `rocker/studio`; my custom image just adds some 3rd party libraries that I use in my project. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file,

```
services:
  rstudio-server:
    image: my-custom/rstudio
    ports:
      - "8787:8787"
    environment:
      PASSWORD: mypassword
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/my-r-project/switch-to-project:/home/rstudio/.local/share/rstudio/projects_settings/switch-to-project
      - /home/ubuntu/my-r-project:/home/rstudio/my-r-project
```

The contents of `switch-to-project` file is,

```
/home/rstudio/my-r-project/my-r-project.Rproj
```

I am getting an error: `Could not connect to the R session on the RStudio Server.`

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a arm64 architecture? There are a number of issues related to the error `Could not connect to the R session on the RStudio Server` like this one: https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/issues/259

Since there isn't an official release of RStudio Server for `arm64` builds, as suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8809#issuecomment-1224983878) this is a Dockerfile that should work on arm64 platforms:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.2.1

ENV S6_VERSION=v2.1.0.2
ENV RSTUDIO_VERSION=daily
ENV DEFAULT_USER=rstudio
ENV PANDOC_VERSION=default
ENV PATH=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin:$PATH

RUN /rocker_scripts/install_rstudio.sh
RUN /rocker_scripts/install_pandoc.sh

EXPOSE 8787
CMD ["/init"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that that's it, I can comment out the volume with `switch-to-project` and it works as intended.